# Format view using @group.fieldData on a lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I'm trying to do some formatting of my document library.  I'm specifically trying to format when I've grouped by a column, this column is a lookup column to another list.

This is the code I'm using.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
    "groupProps": {
        "hideFooter":true,
      "headerFormatter": {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "flex-wrap": "wrap",
          "background-color":"lightgray",
          "display": "flex",
          "box-sizing": "border-box",
          "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
          "border-radius": "6px",
          "align-items": "center",
          "white-space": "nowrap",
          "overflow": "hidden",
          "margin": "1px 4px 4px 1px"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "class": "'sp-field-borderAllRegular sp-css-borderColor-neutralSecondary'"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "style": {
                  "display": "flex",
                  "flex-direction": "row",
                  "justify-content": "center"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "txtContent": "=  @group.count + ' Document(s)'",
                    "style": {
                      "padding": "5px 5px 5px 5px",
                      "font-weight": "500"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "style": {
                  "display": "flex",
                  "flex-direction": "row",
                  "justify-content": "center"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "txtContent": "= 'Agent: ' + @group.fieldData.displayValue",
                    "style": {
                      "padding": " ",
                      "font-weight": "500"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

This is giving me an `[object Object]` result which is really confusing me, I can only assume this is due to it being a lookup column.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if my reply helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 5):

Try using below JSON code:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
    "groupProps": {
        "hideFooter": true,
        "headerFormatter": {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
                "flex-wrap": "wrap",
                "background-color": "lightgray",
                "display": "flex",
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
                "border-radius": "6px",
                "align-items": "center",
                "white-space": "nowrap",
                "overflow": "hidden",
                "margin": "1px 4px 4px 1px"
            },
            "attributes": {
                "class": "'sp-field-borderAllRegular sp-css-borderColor-neutralSecondary'"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "elmType": "div",
                            "style": {
                                "display": "flex",
                                "flex-direction": "row",
                                "justify-content": "center"
                            },
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "elmType": "div",
                                    "txtContent": "=  @group.count + ' Document(s)'",
                                    "style": {
                                        "padding": "5px 5px 5px 5px",
                                        "font-weight": "500"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "elmType": "div",
                            "style": {
                                "display": "flex",
                                "flex-direction": "row",
                                "justify-content": "center"
                            },
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "elmType": "div",
                                    "txtContent": "= 'Agent: ' + @group.fieldData.lookupValue",
                                    "style": {
                                        "padding": " ",
                                        "font-weight": "500"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Use `@group.fieldData.lookupValue` instead of `@group.fieldData.displayValue`

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)

Comment: where did you add the column name in your script?

Comment: I am not showing column name in the JSON, only the column values? What are your requirements? Please Ask a new question.

Comment: very similar to this post.
I have a SharePoint online document library with a lookup column to another SharePoint online list. The allow multiple selections have been enabled in the lookup column in SPO document library. What I want is grouping the lookup column

Comment: You can group based on lookup column from view settings page or from list view by clicking on column name/header. Let me know if it works for you or please [Ask a new question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) where other users can also respond.

Comment: The lookup column I am trying to make the group is unavailable on the view setting page because it allows multiple options to be turned on.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately not possible with SharePoint default functionalities as lookup columns with multiple selection allowed are not supported for grouping list views.